# Repeat range under each other in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a range of two columns with year and dates. In another sheet I want to repeat this range for X amount of times under each other. How can I do this?

So for example I have this range:

```
Year | Month
2012 | 12
2013 | 01
2013 | 02
2013 | 03
```

And I want to be able to say: put that range under each other for X amount of times. For example 3 times:

```
Year | Month
2012 | 12
2013 | 01
2013 | 02
2013 | 03
2012 | 12
2013 | 01
2013 | 02
2013 | 03
2012 | 12
2013 | 01
2013 | 02
2013 | 03
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little script will repeat any range (with or without the header) to the given amount:

```
function output(range,amount,header) {
  var output = [];

  // check if range is cell
  if(typeof range == 'string') {
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      output.push([range]);
    }
    return output;
  } else {
    // check if header is wanted
    var value;
    if(header == 1) {
      output.push(range[0]);
      value=header;
    } else if(header == "") {
      value=0;
    } else {
      value=0;
    }  
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      for(var j=value, jLen=range.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        output.push(range[j]);
      }
    }    
    return output;
  }  
}
```

In order to get the result from your question, use the following formula:
[image]

Under Tools>Script editor you can paste the code. Press the save button and you're on the go !!

I've prepared an example file for you to play around with: **[Repeat Range](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFZ1TGlyRGdMOGFIcklGOTIwT3lNaHc&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1):

You can rept range using formula (for e.g. you need rept range "C1:C4" 2 times):

`=transpose(split(REPT(C1&","&C2&","&C3&","&C4&",";2);",";true))`

Comment: You can link to the cell in another cell (for e.g. data!C1) , and for second column repeat formula with other column character. For `x` - push value for some cell (e.g. A1) and link on it.
`=transpose(split(REPT(data!C1&","&data!C2&",";data!A1);",";true))`

Comment: I'm inclined to leave this for now in the hope that it can be salvaged by editing.  Not sure if that will happen, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate one way to achieve the result (not necessarily the means) I think OP wants. Import data with something like:

```
 =IMPORTRANGE(" k e y ","Sheet1!A1:B5")
```

Assuming `Year` in A1 of Sheet1 and into A1, then in A6 and copied across to B6:

```
 =A2
```

with the pair copied down to suit.