# Repeat a FILTER or ARRAYFORMULA n times?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to repeat an `ARRAYFORMULA` or `FILTER` *n* times. Let's assume I have:

```
   A
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Now I set `=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A3)` and I get the same output. But now I want it to repeat *n* times, let's say three times:

```
   A
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  a
5  b
6  c
7  a
8  b
9  c
```

How can I achieve that?

<sub>I would like to do it without JavaScript.</sub>

Comment: Have a look at this answer I gave: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45557/29140. If you like it, then just give it an upvote !!

Comment: Thank you. I already found that solution. I would like to know if there is a way without JavaScript.

Comment: Entschuldigung, hätte die letzte Bemerkung von Dir nicht gelesen....

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, ich habe jetzt dein Script mal ausprobiert. Es funktioniert sehr gut. Ich habe aber Werte, die von links nach rechts gehen, nicht von oben nach unten. Kann ich das im Script irgendwie ändern? Ich möchte, dass das ARRAY nach dem letzten Werte weitergeführt wird: a b c a b c a b c

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, in A4:

```
=query({A1:A3;A1:A3},"select *")
```