# How to duplicate range of cells n-times(range can variate and must be based on column)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

Can someone explain for me how with the help of formula I can solve this issue? We have an input range of Tags (letters and numbers). Whole massive must be duplicated in the same order n times. The formula should work with column D-D, not with range D1-D6 because number of input values can be changed.
[image]

The idea is that the amount of elements in the input column can variate.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat range under each other in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42711/repeat-range-under-each-other-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: Both variants are not good, in script and formula u need to specify range, not column ((

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that as part of your continuous search/research efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the easier way to get the expected result is by using Copy & Paste

1. Select the range to be copied (`D2:D7`)
2. Copy
3. Select the destination range (`F2:F31`)
4. Paste

If your still prefer to use a formula, the following one will return the required values but not the formatting:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",D2:D7)&",",E2),","))
```

To apply the formatting, you could use [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Advanced

If you need to use "`D:D`" instead of `D2:D7`, replace it by

```
Array_Constrain(D2:D;1,COUNTA(D2:D))
```

Use the use of `D2` as the start cell instead of `D` because the column include a header and it should not be included.

Remarks:

`COUNTA` will work for `TEXT` values. For `NUMBERS` use `COUNT` and if you have mixed value types use `LEN(D2:D)>0`;

Related

- [Repeat range under each other in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42711/)

Comment: I'm posting this in case that the possible duplicate be hard to follow as the accepted answer suggest the use of a custom function (script) and the answer that provides a formula doesn't include any explanation about how it works.

Comment: now its working with numbers, but giving only ,,,,, in case of tags like LBA24

Comment: @Mykyta I'm sorry, there was a typo (replace `COUNT` by `COUNTA`)

Comment: already, now works perfect thank you a lot

Comment: @Mykyta Glad to know. Please accept the answer (click on the tick mark below the answer score / voting arrows)